# automatically adjust height to children's height (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML code like this:

> ```
> <pre><div class="post" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
>  <div class="userpic" style="width:70px;float:left">
>   <img src="XXX"><br>some text
>  </div><!-- /userpic -->
>  <span class="text"><h4>I'm a heading</h4>Just a few words.</span>
> </div><!-- /post --> </pre>
> ```

Sometimes the picure loaded in the userpic-div is higher than the text in the text-span. The post-div, however, stays as high as the text in it is. Now I want it to be at least as high as the userpic-div. I tried to do that with jQuery, here is what I thought:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var elements = $('.post');
    elements.each(function(){
    userpic = $(this).children('.userpic');

        if($(this).height() < userpic.height()){
        $(this).height() = userpic.height();
            }
    });

 });
```

I get no Error (in Chrome) but it doesn't work.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I think you have to wait for all images to load to be able to do that. Try binding to the `load` event of each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have floated content which pulls it out of the flow. You need to clear the float to resume normal content flow.  Try adding `<br style="clear: both" />` to your code, just after the more text.

```
<pre><div class="post" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
 <div class="userpic" style="width:70px;float:left">
  <img src="XXX"><br>some text
 </div><!-- /userpic -->
 <span class="text"><h4>I'm a heading</h4>Just a few words.</span>
 <br style="clear: both;" />
</div><!-- /post --> </pre>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle so that you can see what I mean. As this is a layout issue, you really shouldn't be using javascript to correct the layout. Fix the root of the problem! - http://jsfiddle.net/bD9EV/

Comment: True, never use JS to correct layout problems when can be avoided :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the `height` of an element in jQuery with `height() = someValue`. In fact, it never makes sense to have a function call on the left-hand side of the `=` operator.

Change this line:

```
$(this).height() = userpic.height();
```

to this:

```
$(this).css({height: userpic.height()});
```

Comment: Also, thanks for helping me discover placehold.it! Very useful.

Comment: Hahah.. great tool for developing :)